# Getting this warning: Incompatible pointer types initializing ' *' with an expression with type ' *'

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am getting this warning but have no clue what am I doing wrong, it's a simple code to change views with transitions. I didn't use to have this error with Xcode 3.x but now with 4.x the problem began. Although it's just a warning and the code compiles perfectly, I'd like to know what is the problem.

```
-(IBAction)swapViews:(id)sender{
DemoViewController *view3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
view3.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:view3 animated:YES];}
```

Appreciate all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //DemoViewController*   ThirdViewController*   ????
 //the warning is in this line 
DemoViewController *view3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
view3.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:view3 animated:YES];
```

I think what you want to do here is.

```
ThirdViewController *view3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: I was about to smash my head against the computer. That did the job. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget the curly braces ?

```
-(IBAction)swapViews:(id)sender {
    DemoViewController *view3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    view3.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:view3 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that, already edited it but that wasn't causing the warning.